# Images not appearing after applying Smush

Tags: plugins, cdn

Upon enabling the Smush plugin to compress images, my sites logo and a few other images are not loading. I have tried resizing the images or disabling Bulk Smushing and Lazy Load to no avail. [Here](https://citydiscountfurn.com) is my site where you can see the error on the first page. I do not develop in WordPress, any help appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet is to open a ticket with the SMUSH development team as the images appear to be served via their CDN.  You're getting a 503 error:  `A 503 Service Unavailable error means that the page or resource is unavailable.`  Why it's not available is what you need to solve.  Do you need an account, do you need to pay, are they have technical issues on their end, is the configuration of their plugin incorrect, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.